# UICollectionView selection/deselection methods not triggering

Tags: uicollectionview, xcode8, uipageviewcontroller, programmatically-created, swift3.2

Basically I have a UIPageViewController which has multiple UICollectionView on each pages.

The problem is I can select/deselect on collectionViews inside the first page. But when I switch to second page, numberOfSections, numberOfItemsInSection, cellForItemAt are all called however the selection and deselection delegate methods are not called at all.

here is the link to the code:
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/4eca4ff9f3e4423c01974609aeae5482

Comment: Webpage not found :)

Comment: Yeah, I already deleted the gist. I found out that there's a logic error in the code. the culprit is the line allowSelection = false :)

Answer (score 2):

I can't connect to your link. But you must make sure **delegate** of **UICollectionView** was set and check **allowsMultipleSelection** and **allowsSelection** is **YES**. You can reference links below:
[UICollectionView - didDeselectItemAtIndexPath not called if cell is selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20380512/uicollectionview-diddeselectitematindexpath-not-called-if-cell-is-selected)
[iOS: UICollectionView cell selection not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18950935/ios-uicollectionview-cell-selection-not-working)

Comment: thank you for your immediate response. I found out that it is a logic error. Cause I am preventing users to immediately select from the collection view without clicking on the button first. then on the second page. I did not enable the allowSelection of the collectionView. That was a stupid mistake.

Comment: You add 1 experience :))